# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '<!--[ngClass]' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

I am using angular to render a set of columns using ngFor and I have to set Class and click event of the column dynamically

If the passed index is already available in any of the settings , then i have to disable the column or ignore click events Also set the column class a different value.

The HTML of the td is like below

```
 <td *ngFor='let colData of rowData.columns'                   
    (click)="existsInSelectedColumns(colData.colIndex) ? $event.stopPropagation() : cellClicked(colData.cell)"            
    [ngClass]="existsInSelectedColumns(colData.colIndex) ?'cell-selected':'cell-default'"
    >
  {{colData.colIndex}}-
  {{colData.cell.value}}
</td>
```

The typescript code is like below

```
  selectionSettings: ColumnSelectionSettings = {
    startIndex: -1,
    selections: [
      {
        type: 'Cell 1',
        colIndex: -1
      },
      {
        type: 'Cell 2',
        colIndex: -1
      },
      {
        type: 'Cell 3',
        colIndex: -1
      },
      {
        type: 'Cell 4',
        colIndex: -1
      } 
    ]
  };
  
  
  
  existsInSelectedColumns(selectedIndex) {
    console.log(selectedIndex);
    //check selectedIndex is available in any of the 'colIndex' values returns true
    if(this.selectionSettings.colIndex.includes(selectedIndex))
    {   
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
  }
```

At run time i am getting the error

ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '<!--[ngClass]' is not a valid attribute name.

How can i set the Class name based on the expression

Comment: Please include complete code to reproduce error.

Comment: Your problem is not in the code that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to divide the directives

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let colData of rowData.columns'>
    <td (click)="existsInSelectedColumns(colData.colIndex) ? $event.stopPropagation() : cellClicked(colData.cell)"            
        [ngClass]="existsInSelectedColumns(colData.colIndex) ?'cell-selected':'cell-default'">
        {{colData.colIndex}}-
        {{colData.cell.value}}
    </td>
</ng-container>
```